# How to set proper smtp Gmail settings in Emacs in order to be able to work with `M-x diary-mail-entries`

Tags: email, diary

I tried the following settings in order to work `M-x diary-mail-entries` but it fails. My question is how to put the correct settings in order to be able to work with  `M-x diary-mail-entries` in Emacs.

```
(setq user-full-name "My name")
(setq user-mail-address "my_user_name@gmail.com")

(setq send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
smtpmail-starttls-credentials
'(("smtp.gmail.com" 587 nil nil))
smtpmail-auth-credentials
(expand-file-name "~/.authinfo")
smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
smtpmail-smtp-service 587
smtpmail-debug-info t)
(require 'smtpmail)
```

I get the error

```
Sending via mail...
gnutls.c: [1] (Emacs) GnuTLS library not found
530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. u9sm80344949wjy.37 - gsmtp
221 2.0.0 closing connection u9sm80344949wjy.37 - gsmtp
smtpmail-send-it: Sending failed: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. u9sm80344949wjy.37 - gsmtp
```

Comment: As you've set `smtpmail-debug-info` to `t`, you should have a buffer called `*trace of SMTP session to smtp.gmail.com*` after a failed attempt to send a message.  Could you paste the contents of that buffer into your question?

Comment: @legoscia done.

Comment: Are you using Windows? I wrote [a little guide](http://xn--9dbdkw.se/diary/how_to_enable_GnuTLS_for_Emacs_24_on_Windows/index.en.html) to installing GnuTLS DLLs for Emacs, which seems to be what's missing here.

Comment: @legoscia, I use windows. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @legoscia Thank you, your little guide was very useful and solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

> smtpmail-send-it: Sending failed: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS
>   command first. u9sm80344949wjy.37 - gsmtp

You did not start tls, you need it to open a TLS connection to your gmail account.

Not a direct answer to your request, but this is an Emacs configuration for sending mails with gmail. The gnutls package should be installed system wide ex: apt install gnutls-bin:

```
;; send mail
(setq
send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
user-mail-address "youremail@gmail.com"
smtpmail-starttls-credentials '(("smtp.gmail.com" "587" nil nil))
smtpmail-auth-credentials (expand-file-name "~/.authinfo")
smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
smtpmail-smtp-service 587
smtpmail-debug-info t
starttls-extra-arguments nil
starttls-gnutls-program "/usr/bin/gnutls-cli"
starttls-extra-arguments nil
starttls-use-gnutls t
)
```

Make sure to insert the correct email address and the correct path to gnutls-cli.